# How to start researching information security

Tags: cryptography

I want to go into information security, and i do not know how to start. I know the basics, but are there like any good sources for papers written about the subject?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/wiki/start

Answer (score 3):

A few possible places to start:

1. This community is a very good source of relevant topics. Though it may be too technical sometimes for the inexperienced.
2. As far as I know, the best way is to just be curious. Read about this topic and when you encounter something you are not familiar with, read about that as well.
3. Curiosity will not get you everything though, and you will probably need to spend some time and learn about how computers work and communicate. Resources about that are pretty easy to come by.
4. Since information security is an ever changing topic, with constant advances every day, a good place to read and learn are infosec news outlets. Some that I would recommend: [Security Now](https://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) - a very good infosec podcast that is easy on beginners but gives an in depth coverage. And some text news websites - [Dark Reading](http://www.darkreading.com/), [Naked Security](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/), [Google's project zero](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.co.il/), [Darknet](http://www.darknet.org.uk/), [Malwarebytes labs blog](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/) and there are many many more!

Good luck!

Comment: To add a few resources to the above list -  Infosecurity magazine, Cybrary - free online training, there's a ton of stuff on Pluralsight  (subscription based training) follow industry people on twitter  (troy hunt, krebs,  cluely). You need to think about where to specialise though,  information security is a huge area.

Comment: @iain That's a great point! Choosing one special sub topic of interest is crucial if you want to dig deep into it. Thanks iain!